# SUM of column between current record and next record

Tags: sql-server

Slightly difficult to explain and my SQL Server is not the best but anything will do here.

First, create some tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Quarterly](
[QuarterDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[SomeText] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Quarterly] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[QuarterDate] ASC
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TmpDegreeDays](
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Value] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TmpDegreeDays] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Date] ASC
)
GO
```

Then insert some data:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009CF100000000 AS DateTime), N'Blah')
INSERT [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009D4B00000000 AS DateTime), N'Fools')
INSERT [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009DA600000000 AS DateTime), N'Later')
INSERT [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009E0400000000 AS DateTime), N'Something')
INSERT [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009E5E00000000 AS DateTime), N'New year')
INSERT [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES (CAST(0x00009EC300000000 AS DateTime), N'In april')
```

Then insert date ranges from `2010-01-01` to (including) `2012-03-10` into table `TmpDegreeDays`

Finally:

I want to calculate the SUM of [Value] in `TmpDegreeDays` for each record in the `Quarterly` table between the current `QuarterDate` and the next record in the `Quarterly` resultset.

Something like:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime
SET @startDate = '2010-01-01'
SET @endDate = '2010-12-31'

SELECT q.QuarterDate, q.SomeText, CustomSum = 
(SELECT SUM(CAST([Value] AS float))
FROM TmpDegreeDays 
WHERE [date] >= q.QuarterDate AND *Current QuarterDate* < *Some query here to get next row QuarterDate*)

FROM Quarterly q

WHERE q.QuarterDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Example of final output I am looking for:

```
2010-01-01   Sum of [Value] between 2010-01-01 and 2010-03-31
2010-04-01   Sum of [Value] between 2010-04-01 and 2010-06-30
2010-07-01   Sum of [Value] between 2010-07-01 and 2010-09-31
2010-10-03   Sum of [Value] between 2010-10-03 and 2010-10-03
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: First of all: why are you making your `INSERT` so complicated?? Why not use `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Quarterly] ([QuarterDate], [SomeText]) VALUES ('20100101', N'Blah')` and so on?? **MUCH** easier than that odd casting of yours..... also: if you have a table with degree values - **WHY** is the `Value` column a `VARCHAR(50)` ?? Shouldn't that be something like `DECIMAL(10,4)` or something more like that??? Varchar totally doesn't make sense here.....

Comment: Marc - it isnt my code :-) im just taking it on. believe me, it would be done much better

Comment: But a `SUM` won't even **work** on a `VARCHAR` column - you will definitely have to change some things.....

Comment: dont worry marc, I will! like I said, its something im looking through and been given it....

Comment: Marc - almost there. The problem I have is with the QuarterDate and the 3 months you add. I need to remove this as every "customer" has their own definition of what a Quarter could be (From a calander table). I need to obtain the next QuarterDate from the next row of data and use that as the "end". any ideas? (like in my original post but last comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this - using a CTE (available in SQL Server **2005** and newer) to find the dates for each quarter and then summing up the degree values:

```
;WITH QuarterlyDates AS
(        
   SELECT 
       QuarterDate, 
       QuarterEndDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, QuarterDate))
   FROM [dbo].[Quarterly]
)
SELECT
    qd.QuarterDate, qd.QuarterEndDate,
    DegreeSum = (SELECT SUM(DegreeValue) 
                 FROM [dbo].[TmpDegreeDays] 
                 WHERE [Date] BETWEEN qd.QuarterDate AND qd.QuarterEndDate)
FROM
    QuarterlyDates qd
```

The strange function to determine the `QuarterEndDate` is rooted in the fact that the `DATETIME` has a precision of 3.33ms in SQL Server. Thus, the last date for a given month is the last day of that month, and the time is `23:59:59.997` (not .999). Therefore, I need to add three months to the quarter's start date, and then subtract 3 milliseconds from that start date of the next quarter to get the last millisecond of this quarter in question.

**Update:** OK, in order to get the start and end date for a quarter from the table, you need two nested CTE's in order to determine the "end date of the next quarter minus 3 milliseconds" for the end of the quarter - something like this:

```
;WITH QuarterStarts AS
(
    SELECT  
        QuarterDate,
        QNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY QuarterDate)   -- ordering number
    FROM [dbo].[Quarterly]
),
Quarters AS
(
    SELECT
        QuarterStartDate = q1.QuarterDate,
        QuarterEndDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, q2.QuarterDate) 
    FROM
        QuarterStarts q1
    INNER JOIN 
        QuarterStarts q2 ON q2.QNumber = q1.QNumber + 1 
)
SELECT
    q.QuarterDate, q.QuarterEndDate,
    DegreeSum = (SELECT SUM(DegreeValue) 
                 FROM [dbo].[TmpDegreeDays] 
                 WHERE [Date] BETWEEN q.QuarterDate AND q.QuarterEndDate)
FROM
    Quarters q
```

Comment: Marc - great! I think this is it. One problem though - the CTE needs to be in a Column of the final resultset (still selecting only from the QuarterDates table) which is far far down in the original PROC I have stripped out and simplified here. There are custom  columns being created to be returned in the final resultset (such as some calculations). So how can I still reference the CTE further down in the SPROC?

Comment: Marc - almost there. The problem I have is with the QuarterDate and the 3 months you add. I need to remove this as every "customer" has their own definition of what a Quarter could be (From a calander table). I need to obtain the next QuarterDate from the next row of data and use that as the "end". any ideas?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: updated my response with an approach to determine the end of the current quarter by looking at the start date of the next one

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: sorry - I had one of my table variables in there that I made up for testing. Fixed it - try again, please.